# Correlation coefficient of total population is greater than population samples

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, correlation

I have created two classifiers, a Boosted Decision Tree (BDT), and a Neural Network (NN) to classify events as either belonging to a signal class or background class. They output a continuous probability between 0 and 1 of belonging to the signal class. I want to compare the two methods and wish to find the correlation between the two.

However I find that if I calculate the correlation coefficient of just the events that belong to the background class, or the events that just belong to the signal class, these correlations are smaller than correlation of the entire dataset. I would have assumed that as both classifiers are tested on the exact same dataset the total correlation would be a weighted average of the two individual correlations. Note that the total dataset consists of ~100,000 events.

Here I calculate the correlation for the whole dataset using the pandas .corr() function which calculates the Pearson correlation matrix:

```
dfBDT = pd.read_csv("BDTResults.csv")
dfNN = pd.read_csv("NNResults.csv")

# not defaulted by Event Number by default
dfBDT = dfBDT.sort_values('EventNumber')
dfNN = dfNN.sort_values('EventNumber')

# Resets index of sorted dataframe so sorted dataframe index begins at 0
dfBDT.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dfNN.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

dfscore = pd.concat([dfBDT['score'],dfNN['score']], axis = 1)
dfnum = pd.concat([dfBDT['EventNumber'],dfNN['EventNumber']], axis = 1)

dfTotal = pd.concat([dfnum,dfscore], axis = 1)
dfTotal.columns = ['EventNumberBDT', 'EventNumberNN', 'BDT', 'NN']

dfTotal.corr()
```

This gives a 97% correlation. I then do the same just for the background events where I have defined the background events to have a class of 0:

```
BDT_back = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 0])['score']
BDT_back.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

BDT_back_num = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 0])['EventNumber']
BDT_back_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


NN_back = (dfNN.loc[dfNN['Class'] == 0])['score']
NN_back.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

NN_back_num = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 0])['EventNumber']
NN_back_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)



dfBack = pd.concat([BDT_back_num,NN_back_num,BDT_back,NN_back],
                   axis = 1)
dfBack.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

dfBack.columns = ['EventNumberBDT','EventNumberNN','BDT','NN']

dfBack.corr()
```

This gives me a correlation of about 96%. I then just repeat above for the signal events, i.e. replace class = 0 with class = 1 and I get a correlations of 91%.

Then if I try rejoining the two dataframes and calculate the total correlation again I get a higher correlation than before of 98%:

```
ab = pd.concat([dfBack['BDT'],dfSig['BDT']])
ba = pd.concat([dfBack['NN'],dfSig['NN']])

abba =pd.concat([ab,ba], axis = 1)
abba.corr()
```

The fact that these two values are different must mean that something is going wrong but I do not know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it comes down to the horizontal merges that run on indexes.

**Unmatched Rows**

If rows differ by both data frames, `concat` that defaults to outer join will generate `NaN` at unmatched indexes (on data frame of lesser rows) which would be more rows than original data frame before splitting.

**Unmatched Classes**

Additionally, if *Class* have different % shares between the two data frames, *dfBDT* and *dfNN*, their corresponding joins will return `NaN` at unmatched indexes.

For example, let's say *dfBDT* maintains 60% and 40% between Class 0 and 1 and *dfNN* maintains 50% and 50% between Class 0 and 1 where comparisons include:

- BDT Class 0 will have *more* rows than NN Class 0
- BDT Class 1 will have *less* rows than NN Class 1

After horizontal join with `pd.concat(..., axis = 1)` which defaults to outer join, `how = 'outer'`, the resulting mismatches will generate `NaN` on both sides. Even if you do use `how='inner`', you will be filtering out mismatches but *dfTotal* never filters out any rows but includes **all** rows.

**Sort Order**

Testing between Linux and Windows machines with seeded, reproducible example indicates sorting matters, specifically by `Class` first then `EventNumber` matters.

---

This can be demonstrated with seeded, random data for a reproducible example. Below refactors your code to avoid the many `pd.concat` calls with use of `join` (adjusting its default to `how='outer'`). Further down this code is equivalent to OP's original setup.

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2292020)
dfBDT = pd.DataFrame({'EventNumber': np.random.randint(1, 15, 500),
                      'Class': np.random.randint(0, 1, 500),
                      'score': np.random.randn(500)
                     })


dfNN = pd.DataFrame({'EventNumber': np.random.randint(1, 15, 500),
                     'Class': np.random.randint(0, 1, 500),
                     'score': np.random.randn(500)
                    })
```

**Code**

```
dfBDT = dfBDT.sort_values(['Class', 'EventNumber']).reset_index(drop=True)    
dfNN = dfNN.sort_values(['Class', 'EventNumber']).reset_index(drop=True)  

# ALL ROWS (NO FILTER)
dfTotal = (dfBDT.reindex(['EventNumber', 'score'], axis='columns')
                .join(dfNN.reindex(['EventNumber', 'score'], axis='columns'),
                      rsuffix = '_')
                .set_axis(['EventNumberBDT', 'BDT', 'EventNumberNN', 'NN'], 
                          axis='columns', inplace = False)
                .reindex(['EventNumberBDT','EventNumberNN','BDT','NN'], 
                         axis='columns'))    
dfTotal.corr()

# TWO FILTERED DATA FRAMES CLASS (0 FOR BACKGROUND, 1 FOR SIGNAL)
df_list = [(dfBDT.query('Class == {}'.format(i))
                 .reindex(['EventNumber', 'score'], axis='columns')
                 .join(dfNN.query('Class == {}'.format(i))
                           .reindex(['EventNumber', 'score'], axis='columns'),
                       rsuffix = '_')
                 .set_axis(['EventNumberBDT', 'BDT', 'EventNumberNN', 'NN'],
                           axis='columns', inplace = False)

                 .reindex(['EventNumberBDT','EventNumberNN','BDT','NN'],
                          axis='columns')
           ) for i in range(0,2)]

dfSub = pd.concat(df_list)

dfSub.corr()
```

**Output** *(notice they return different results)*

```
dfTotal.corr()
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.912279 -0.024121  0.115754
# EventNumberNN         0.912279       1.000000 -0.039038  0.122905
# BDT                  -0.024121      -0.039038  1.000000  0.012143
# NN                    0.115754       0.122905  0.012143  1.000000

dfSub.corr()
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.974140 -0.024121  0.120102
# EventNumberNN         0.974140       1.000000 -0.026026  0.122905
# BDT                  -0.024121      -0.026026  1.000000  0.025548
# NN                    0.120102       0.122905  0.025548  1.000000
```

However, if we equate *Class* shares (such as 50% and 50% across both data frames or any share equivalent in both data frames), outputs match exactly.

```
np.random.seed(2292020)
dfBDT = pd.DataFrame({'EventNumber': np.random.randint(1, 15, 500),
                      'Class': np.concatenate((np.zeros(250), np.ones(250))),
                      'score': np.random.randn(500)
                     })


dfNN = pd.DataFrame({'EventNumber': np.random.randint(1, 15, 500),
                     'Class': np.concatenate((np.zeros(250), np.ones(250))),
                     'score': np.random.randn(500)
                    })

...

dfTotal.corr()
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.992846 -0.026130  0.023623
# EventNumberNN         0.992846       1.000000 -0.023411  0.022093
# BDT                  -0.026130      -0.023411  1.000000 -0.026454
# NN                    0.023623       0.022093 -0.026454  1.000000


dfSub.corr()
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.992846 -0.026130  0.023623
# EventNumberNN         0.992846       1.000000 -0.023411  0.022093
# BDT                  -0.026130      -0.023411  1.000000 -0.026454
# NN                    0.023623       0.022093 -0.026454  1.000000
```

---

Finally, this has been tested with OP's original code:

```
def op_approach_total():
    dfscore = pd.concat([dfBDT['score'],dfNN['score']], axis = 1)
    dfnum = pd.concat([dfBDT['EventNumber'],dfNN['EventNumber']], axis = 1)

    dfTotal = pd.concat([dfnum,dfscore], axis = 1)
    dfTotal.columns = ['EventNumberBDT', 'EventNumberNN', 'BDT', 'NN']

    return dfTotal.corr()


def op_approach_split():
    # not defaulted by Event Number by default
    BDT_back = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 0])['score']
    BDT_back.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    BDT_back_num = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 0])['EventNumber']
    BDT_back_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


    NN_back = (dfNN.loc[dfNN['Class'] == 0])['score']
    NN_back.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    NN_back_num = (dfNN.loc[dfNN['Class'] == 0])['EventNumber'] 
    NN_back_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


    dfBack = pd.concat([BDT_back_num,NN_back_num,BDT_back,NN_back],
                       axis = 1)
    dfBack.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    dfBack.columns = ['EventNumberBDT','EventNumberNN','BDT','NN']


    # not defaulted by Event Number by default
    BDT_sig = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 1])['score']
    BDT_sig.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    BDT_sig_num = (dfBDT.loc[dfBDT['Class'] == 1])['EventNumber']
    BDT_sig_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    NN_sig = (dfNN.loc[dfNN['Class'] == 1])['score']
    NN_sig.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    NN_sig_num = (dfNN.loc[dfNN['Class'] == 1])['EventNumber']
    NN_sig_num.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


    dfSig = pd.concat([BDT_sig_num, NN_sig_num, BDT_sig, NN_sig],
                       axis = 1)
    dfSig.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    dfSig.columns = ['EventNumberBDT','EventNumberNN','BDT','NN']

    # ADDING EventNumber COLUMNS
    ev_back = pd.concat([dfBack['EventNumberBDT'], dfSig['EventNumberBDT']])
    ev_sig = pd.concat([dfBack['EventNumberNN'], dfSig['EventNumberNN']])


    ab = pd.concat([dfBack['BDT'], dfSig['BDT']])

    ba = pd.concat([dfBack['NN'], dfSig['NN']])

    # HORIZONTAL MERGE
    abba = pd.concat([ev_back, ev_sig, ab, ba], axis = 1)

    return abba.corr()

opTotal = op_approach_total()
opSub = op_approach_split()
```

**Output**

```
opTotal = op_approach_total()
opTotal
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.992846 -0.026130  0.023623
# EventNumberNN         0.992846       1.000000 -0.023411  0.022093
# BDT                  -0.026130      -0.023411  1.000000 -0.026454
# NN                    0.023623       0.022093 -0.026454  1.000000

opSub = op_approach_split()
opSub
#                 EventNumberBDT  EventNumberNN       BDT        NN
# EventNumberBDT        1.000000       0.992846 -0.026130  0.023623
# EventNumberNN         0.992846       1.000000 -0.023411  0.022093
# BDT                  -0.026130      -0.023411  1.000000 -0.026454
# NN                    0.023623       0.022093 -0.026454  1.000000
```

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that typo. Both classifiers were trained on the same datasets and as such should have the same split between classes. In my original code I did include a check for an NaN values and when I run 
`print(len(dfBDT[dfBDT['Class'] == 1]))
print(len(dfBDT[dfBDT['Class'] == 0]))

print(len(dfNN[dfNN['Class'] == 1]))
print(len(dfNN[dfNN['Class'] == 0]))`
I get the same amount between each classifier and yet I still get this issue. There may be a deeper issue I am missing then but it seems I still have a lot to learn about manipulating dataframes

Comment: Do you have other values in `Class` other than 0 or 1, including `NaN`? Those `len` calls do not directly check `NaN`. I should also point out the number of rows must be same in both data frames not just equal *Class* shares as unmatched indexes with outer join will generate `NaN`.

Comment: There are only the two classes, the length of both dataframes is the same, with the sum of the lengths of the 0 class and 1 class equalling the length of the dataframe. I'll maybe try it with a reduced dataset instead of the full ~100,000 events

Comment: Interestingly, testing now on Windows machine (earlier solution ran on Linux) with reproducible example of same rows and same *Class* shares reveals one other criteria is needed: data must be sorted by *Class* (before *EventNumber*). See edit. Also, click run on this [Pyfiddle Demo](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/75a755b4-83de-44ee-af0b-d0303d935db4/?m=Saved%20fiddle) using a *Class* share of 75% zeros and 25% ones.

Comment: Yeah that fixed that issue, although I don't understand why exactly it  was necessary to sort by class first. So I now know the total correlation is consistent, to check how the classifiers correlate individually surely I just need to return dfSig.corr() and dfBack.corr() at the end of op_approach_split(). These correlations are lower than the total correlation. I still don't see how the data could become more correlated, is this another sorting issue?

Comment: Sorting matters with correlations since it rearranges observations and an integral step is the cross products by each row. See pearson and other formulas. As for why your split correlations are lower than total, that is a data-specific question and can change with different samples? Plus, you do not explain which correlation statistic out of all reported in matrix is the issue.

Comment: The only correlations in the matrix I am actually interested in is the BDT NN terms, not the terms involving the event numbers